# CRC-32 on MicroController (Atmel)

Tags: c, avr, crc32, atmega

I am currently trying to implement a CRC-32 for an incoming datastream (Serial communication) on an ATMEGA1280 and I am a little lost how to do this on the embedded side in C.... If anyone could point me in the proper direction and/or help in anyway i would greatly appreciate it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know what polynomial you are dealing with. So it is not enough to know that you are using CRC, but you should also know polynomial.

You are looking for function with this kind of prototype

```
 uint32_t crc(uint8_t * data, int len, uint32_t polynomial)
```

Or even further, this function can also support updating if you getting your data asynchronously, so there is extra parameter for resuming computation.

With CRC32 you stream bits through CRC function and you get 32 bit number that is used for data corruption checking.

I am sure you will be able to find C code of crc online.

EDIT:

It looks like, CRC32 polynomial is sort of standard and is usually unified. 
That mean that CRC32 implementation will employ correct polynomial.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_CRC

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of CRC-32 implementations in C. The AT MEGA1280 has 128 KB of code space, it shoudn't have any problems running any off-the-shelf implementation.

[Here](http://www.csbruce.com/~csbruce/software/crc32.c) is pretty much the first one I found.

Answer (score 0):

Copy-paste solution for AVR, ripped from [here](http://code.google.com/p/avr-cs/source/browse/trunk/newcamd_client_pc/src/cscrypt/crc32.c?spec=svn11&r=11):

```
/* crc32.c -- compute the CRC-32 of a data stream
 * Copyright (C) 1995-1996 Mark Adler
 * For conditions of distribution and use, see copyright notice in zlib.h 
 */

/* $Id: crc32.c,v 1.1 2007/10/07 20:47:35 matthias Exp $ */

/* ========================================================================
 * Table of CRC-32's of all single-byte values (made by make_crc_table)
 */
static unsigned long crc_table[256] = {
  0x00000000L, 0x77073096L, 0xee0e612cL, 0x990951baL, 0x076dc419L,
  0x706af48fL, 0xe963a535L, 0x9e6495a3L, 0x0edb8832L, 0x79dcb8a4L,
  0xe0d5e91eL, 0x97d2d988L, 0x09b64c2bL, 0x7eb17cbdL, 0xe7b82d07L,
  0x90bf1d91L, 0x1db71064L, 0x6ab020f2L, 0xf3b97148L, 0x84be41deL,
  0x1adad47dL, 0x6ddde4ebL, 0xf4d4b551L, 0x83d385c7L, 0x136c9856L,
  0x646ba8c0L, 0xfd62f97aL, 0x8a65c9ecL, 0x14015c4fL, 0x63066cd9L,
  0xfa0f3d63L, 0x8d080df5L, 0x3b6e20c8L, 0x4c69105eL, 0xd56041e4L,
  0xa2677172L, 0x3c03e4d1L, 0x4b04d447L, 0xd20d85fdL, 0xa50ab56bL,
  0x35b5a8faL, 0x42b2986cL, 0xdbbbc9d6L, 0xacbcf940L, 0x32d86ce3L,
  0x45df5c75L, 0xdcd60dcfL, 0xabd13d59L, 0x26d930acL, 0x51de003aL,
  0xc8d75180L, 0xbfd06116L, 0x21b4f4b5L, 0x56b3c423L, 0xcfba9599L,
  0xb8bda50fL, 0x2802b89eL, 0x5f058808L, 0xc60cd9b2L, 0xb10be924L,
  0x2f6f7c87L, 0x58684c11L, 0xc1611dabL, 0xb6662d3dL, 0x76dc4190L,
  0x01db7106L, 0x98d220bcL, 0xefd5102aL, 0x71b18589L, 0x06b6b51fL,
  0x9fbfe4a5L, 0xe8b8d433L, 0x7807c9a2L, 0x0f00f934L, 0x9609a88eL,
  0xe10e9818L, 0x7f6a0dbbL, 0x086d3d2dL, 0x91646c97L, 0xe6635c01L,
  0x6b6b51f4L, 0x1c6c6162L, 0x856530d8L, 0xf262004eL, 0x6c0695edL,
  0x1b01a57bL, 0x8208f4c1L, 0xf50fc457L, 0x65b0d9c6L, 0x12b7e950L,
  0x8bbeb8eaL, 0xfcb9887cL, 0x62dd1ddfL, 0x15da2d49L, 0x8cd37cf3L,
  0xfbd44c65L, 0x4db26158L, 0x3ab551ceL, 0xa3bc0074L, 0xd4bb30e2L,
  0x4adfa541L, 0x3dd895d7L, 0xa4d1c46dL, 0xd3d6f4fbL, 0x4369e96aL,
  0x346ed9fcL, 0xad678846L, 0xda60b8d0L, 0x44042d73L, 0x33031de5L,
  0xaa0a4c5fL, 0xdd0d7cc9L, 0x5005713cL, 0x270241aaL, 0xbe0b1010L,
  0xc90c2086L, 0x5768b525L, 0x206f85b3L, 0xb966d409L, 0xce61e49fL,
  0x5edef90eL, 0x29d9c998L, 0xb0d09822L, 0xc7d7a8b4L, 0x59b33d17L,
  0x2eb40d81L, 0xb7bd5c3bL, 0xc0ba6cadL, 0xedb88320L, 0x9abfb3b6L,
  0x03b6e20cL, 0x74b1d29aL, 0xead54739L, 0x9dd277afL, 0x04db2615L,
  0x73dc1683L, 0xe3630b12L, 0x94643b84L, 0x0d6d6a3eL, 0x7a6a5aa8L,
  0xe40ecf0bL, 0x9309ff9dL, 0x0a00ae27L, 0x7d079eb1L, 0xf00f9344L,
  0x8708a3d2L, 0x1e01f268L, 0x6906c2feL, 0xf762575dL, 0x806567cbL,
  0x196c3671L, 0x6e6b06e7L, 0xfed41b76L, 0x89d32be0L, 0x10da7a5aL,
  0x67dd4accL, 0xf9b9df6fL, 0x8ebeeff9L, 0x17b7be43L, 0x60b08ed5L,
  0xd6d6a3e8L, 0xa1d1937eL, 0x38d8c2c4L, 0x4fdff252L, 0xd1bb67f1L,
  0xa6bc5767L, 0x3fb506ddL, 0x48b2364bL, 0xd80d2bdaL, 0xaf0a1b4cL,
  0x36034af6L, 0x41047a60L, 0xdf60efc3L, 0xa867df55L, 0x316e8eefL,
  0x4669be79L, 0xcb61b38cL, 0xbc66831aL, 0x256fd2a0L, 0x5268e236L,
  0xcc0c7795L, 0xbb0b4703L, 0x220216b9L, 0x5505262fL, 0xc5ba3bbeL,
  0xb2bd0b28L, 0x2bb45a92L, 0x5cb36a04L, 0xc2d7ffa7L, 0xb5d0cf31L,
  0x2cd99e8bL, 0x5bdeae1dL, 0x9b64c2b0L, 0xec63f226L, 0x756aa39cL,
  0x026d930aL, 0x9c0906a9L, 0xeb0e363fL, 0x72076785L, 0x05005713L,
  0x95bf4a82L, 0xe2b87a14L, 0x7bb12baeL, 0x0cb61b38L, 0x92d28e9bL,
  0xe5d5be0dL, 0x7cdcefb7L, 0x0bdbdf21L, 0x86d3d2d4L, 0xf1d4e242L,
  0x68ddb3f8L, 0x1fda836eL, 0x81be16cdL, 0xf6b9265bL, 0x6fb077e1L,
  0x18b74777L, 0x88085ae6L, 0xff0f6a70L, 0x66063bcaL, 0x11010b5cL,
  0x8f659effL, 0xf862ae69L, 0x616bffd3L, 0x166ccf45L, 0xa00ae278L,
  0xd70dd2eeL, 0x4e048354L, 0x3903b3c2L, 0xa7672661L, 0xd06016f7L,
  0x4969474dL, 0x3e6e77dbL, 0xaed16a4aL, 0xd9d65adcL, 0x40df0b66L,
  0x37d83bf0L, 0xa9bcae53L, 0xdebb9ec5L, 0x47b2cf7fL, 0x30b5ffe9L,
  0xbdbdf21cL, 0xcabac28aL, 0x53b39330L, 0x24b4a3a6L, 0xbad03605L,
  0xcdd70693L, 0x54de5729L, 0x23d967bfL, 0xb3667a2eL, 0xc4614ab8L,
  0x5d681b02L, 0x2a6f2b94L, 0xb40bbe37L, 0xc30c8ea1L, 0x5a05df1bL,
  0x2d02ef8dL
};

#define DO1(buf) crc = crc_table[((int)crc ^ (*buf++)) & 0xff] ^ (crc >> 8);
#define DO2(buf) DO1(buf); DO1(buf);
#define DO4(buf) DO2(buf); DO2(buf);
#define DO8(buf) DO4(buf); DO4(buf);

unsigned long crc32(crc, buf, len)
    unsigned long crc;
    const unsigned char *buf;
    unsigned int len;
{
    if (!buf) return(0L);
    crc = crc ^ 0xffffffffL;
    while (len >= 8)
    {
      DO8(buf);
      len -= 8;
    }
    if (len) do {
      DO1(buf);
    } while (--len);
    return(crc^0xffffffffL);
}
```